# Is it a good practice to use Singleton Facades?

Tags: asp.net, singleton, facade

Is it a good practice to implement the Facade pattern creating Singleton objects?

In the project I am developing, the facade object are going to be called from ASP.NET webforms server-side code, in order to encapsulate the domain logic.

**EXAMPLE:**

> ```
> public sealed class UserFacade
> {
>
>   private static UserFacade instance = null;
>
>   private UserFacade()
>   {
>   }
>
>   public static UserFacade Instance {
>       get {
>           if (instance == null) {
>               instance = new UserFacade();
>           }
>           return instance;
>       }
>   }
>
>
>   public void DoSomethingRelatedWithUsers()
>   {
>       //Logic here
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please illustrate how you envision this, preferably with some code, as your question lacks a bit of body, so it's a little unclear what exactly you mean. Do you mean you have a facade class that you want to turn into a singleton?

Comment: I have a facade class implementing singleton pattern and I am reconsidering if it is better to convert to a normal instantiable class. I'll add an example.

Comment: `static` objects and multi-threaded environments generally don't go well together.